# why artisan command not clearing cache in laravel

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-artisan

I have written the logic to get the user-name of registered users from DB and used it as URL prefix in my web.php and grouped some routes using those name.

On my local machine it seems to working fine. In case of server users can register, but that user is not able to access the further routes with their username as prefix. When tried to access it shows 404.

When did the research it was due to routes not getting cleared. So, after new user registration successfully added the below code to clear cache and route. but still not working. How can i achieve this.

Added on top;

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
```

```
Artisan::call('route:clear'); 
Artisan::call('cache:clear');
```

I have tried clearing cache manually it works fine. But i am trying to do it via code automatically. Also FYI i am not getting any error. because i have tried adding logs and used

```
Artisan::output()
```

to check it, shows success message without any error

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can call the default laravel artisan commands via that facade. What I am sure is that if you want to programmatically delete the cache you should use the Cache facade like so

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

Cache::flush();
```

More info about it [in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/cache).

Comment: Hey @dz0nika Thank you. i don't think that is good idea, though i tried it. To clear cache of entire application, which i might be using some other place. Its causing issues. We just need to reset or clear route.